# Python recursive turtle fractal

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I am trying to write a recursive turtle program that will draw a fractal tree recreating the shape below:

[Turtle Fractal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60tjo.jpg)

This should be done with depth = 3, so three different levels of squares. My issue is that with the code I have already, the turtle on screen still doesn't move. Here is my code so far, any help is appreciated:

```
import turtle
def main():
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.screensize(1000,1000)
    turtle.exitonclick()
    turt = turtle.Turtle()
    squares(turt, length, depth)
def squares(t,length, depth):
    length = 200
    depth = 3
    amt = 1
    if depth == 0:
        return
    elif depth == 3:
        t.penup()
        t.goto(-1000,-1000)
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(length)
        squares(t, length/2, depth - 1)
    elif depth == 2:
```

Comment: Do you have code in which you have successfully moved the turtle?  You might start with that.  If not, you should conquer that problem first with a shorter program, before writing so much code at once.

Comment: Yea I have written turtle programs before, the issue with this is that it uses t as a variable and I am not sure how that affects it in addition to it being recursive

Comment: Have you put in print statements to check whether you're getting into your code at all?  In my IDE, this merely defines two routines and quits: I need a final command `main()` at the bottom to make it run.

Comment: `t.penup()` where is `t.pendown()`?

Answer (score 0):

This incomplete `elif` will keep the code from even running:

```
elif depth == 2:
```

You define `main()`, but fail to call it:

```
def main():
```

You need to add an explicit call to main() at the end:

```
main()
```

Should you actually call `main()`, this premature `exitionclick()` will turn control over to tkinter before you ever invoke `squares()`:

```
turtle.exitonclick()
turt = turtle.Turtle()
squares(turt, length, depthc)
```

the `exitonclick()` should be the last statement of `main()`, or happen after main outside the function.  Your recursion will never happen as you overwrite two of your arguments:

```
def squares(t,length, depth):
    length = 200
    depth = 3
```

so `length` and `depth` will never change despite this test:

```
if depth == 0:
    return
```

Fixing all of these won't get you a program that draws the fractal you desire, but fixing them is likely a necessary first step.

To make the code draw a fractal, you need to interlace the call to `squares()` with each forward motion of the turtle.  Not do it just at the end:

```
    t.forward(length)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(length)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(length)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(length)
    squares(t, length/2, depth - 1)
```

But something more like:

```
for _ in range(4):
    t.forward(length / 4)
    if depth > 1:
        t.right(90)
        squares(t, length / 2, depth - 1)
        t.left(90)
    t.forward(3 * length / 4)
    ...
```

An absolute value like this is to be avoided in a recursive fractal:

```
t.goto(-1000,-1000)
```

And of course, keep your `pendown()` calls properly matched to your `penup()` calls.

[image]